# How to render formatted text in ReactJS webapp?

Tags: reactjs

I need to save, retrieve, render and edit formatted text in my webapp.

For example, I edit text with markddown syntax on the clientSide.
I can convert it to html or save as it is.
But how should i render this text when webapp receiving it as a string?

```
var formattedTextFromDataBase = "<p>some <em>formatted</em> text</p>"
```

I know about "dangerouslysetinnerhtml" - this method seemed to be a bad idea. Is there another way to deal with formatted text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. If you want to render html provided from an external source, `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` was created for that purpose.  As long as the source of the html is trusted (as is the case if users are only seeing their own html rendered), it should be fine.

Comment: thank you!  
If i will save text in markdown syntax and convert it to html only right before rendering - will this way protect me from any js injections? I use this: github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js

Comment: It's not really a matter of when you convert it, rather how you use the user-supplied html on your site, and whether the library used to convert the markdown is trusted.